# Wakanda studio datepicker missing

Tags: datepicker, wakanda

Is it just me? In my Wakanda Studio 1.1.1 the datepicker properties (enable & button) have disappeared from the date textinputs.

I can't find any documentation for such a change to the widget. Perhaps I have an uninstalled dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda [TextInput v2 widget](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Widgets-Instance-API/Text-Input-v2.201-1086764.en.html) never supported any datepicker. You can set the `inputType` property to `date` and then let the client browser handle it.

Chrome, Firefox and mobile browsers usually generate visual datepickers with `<input type="date"/>` inputs.

NOTE: Wakanda [TextInput v1 widget](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Prototyper/Prototyper-Widgets/Text-Input.300-661435.en.html) has a datepicker option. However it's now deprecated and I don't suggest you using it on mobile devices. Using TextInput v2 and choosing a datepicker plugin of your choice is a better alternative.